# Opencart custom footer position not showing data

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to add a custom position in my opencart footer. I did as mentioned in [this site](http://www.deshisoft.com/how-can-i-add-a-new-module-position-for-opencart/) but when I echo `$content_footer` it always gives `null`.

I have assigned the content through the admin and when I do a `var dump` on the `content_footer` controller it shows all the data relevant for the footer position but not in the site footer

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First two things that come to my mind when reading your question and the tutorial: by any chance aren't you working with OC 2.0 (tutorial is for OC 1.5.X); by any chance didn't you create/edit template files in default theme but your site is using different theme?

Comment: @shadyyx thanks for the reply. actually i did made a typo. I echo `$content_footer`. im working on OC 1.5.6. Im using a a custom theme and i have created all the relevant files checked 3 times. I cant find what im doing wrong

Comment: So in your `ControllerCommonContentFooter` if you do a `var_dump($this->data['modules']);` before `$this->render();` you can see some modules data there? And in the `content_footer.tpl` template if you do `var_dump($modules);` can you see the data? And in `footer.tpl` the variable `$content_footer` is empty, right? I think the tutorial may be wrong a little - I am not sure if a child (footer) can load another child (footer_content). Try to edit e.g. `ControllerProductProduct`, find `$this->children = array(...);` and add here `'common/content_footer',` and check in product detail page.

Comment: OK, I checked OC, it looks like loading a child from a child is possible. So loading `common/content_footer` from `common/footer` should be possible as well.